# Erro em arquivo .js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Incluí um arquivo .js em um projeto MVC. meu arquivo .js está assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function escondePanel(painel) {
        $("#pnPessoal").css("display", "none");
        $("#pnContato").css("display", "none");
        $("#pnDocumento").css("display", "none");
        $("#pnOutro").css("display", "none");
        $(painel).css("display", "block");
    }

    $("#pessoal").on("click", function () {
        escondePanel("#pnPessoal");
    });

    $("#contato").on("click", function () {
        escondePanel("#pnContato");
    });

    $("#documento").on("click", function () {
        escondePanel("#pnDocumento");
    });

    $("#outro").on("click", function () {
        escondePanel("#pnOutro");
    });

});
```

Incluí o arquivo .js na Mmnha view assim:

`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/code-servidor.js")`

Porém o código não está funcionando e estou recebendo o erro no console:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined - linha 1.1

O que está errado? Pois copiei a estrutura de um outro arquivo meu que funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando incluir (importar) o **jQuery**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```